# Downgraded HP Pavilion DV9205 from Vista to XP - No network driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, windows-vista

I was recently forced to do a complete new install on this machine, and having only XP, forced to downgrade to XP SP2.  Now XP doesn't see my network adaptor, only sees the 1394 adaptor, which is apparently Firewire.

Short of re-installing with Vista, is there anything I can do driver wise etc. to get XP to see the network card?  HP don't list a NIC driver for XP.

Comment: @ProfKoas Been here for a while actually. I make my rounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more information on [this](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/bizsupport/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1252587704498+28353475&threadId=1113065) HP forum thread. Basically, the drivers for Windows XP are [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=228&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=3340198&lang=en), but you should read the whole thread for more info.

Comment: Glad to know it helped! If you want, consider marking my answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Consider it done :-)

Comment: Sadly, the link to the forum doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Install chipset and other drivers for notebook. Since you can't get to Internet, download corresponding drivers on other PC, copy them to USB or CD and install on Pavilion.

Comment: I kinda figured that part out. ;-)